# How to create multiline text area in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create the following textfield. But there are no samples on the internet for the same, neither in material documentation
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  @Composable
    fun Textarea() {
    val text = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = text.value,
        onValueChange = { text.value = it }, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    )
}
```

You can change the size and customize it as you want as per your requirement.

Comment: you also just use the singleLine attribute of the textField